# Cant print binary variable

Tags: elixir

I have a simple variable declared

```
h = "a"
```

when I try to to `<<h>>` I get

```
> ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>     (stdlib) eval_bits.erl:101: :eval_bits.eval_exp_field1/6
>     (stdlib) eval_bits.erl:92: :eval_bits.eval_field/3
>     (stdlib) eval_bits.erl:68: :eval_bits.expr_grp/4
>     (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:484: :erl_eval.expr/5
>     (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:257: IEx.Evaluator.handle_eval/5
>     (iex) lib/iex/evaluator.ex:237: IEx.Evaluator.do_eval/3
```

If `h` holds the value `"a"` here I can successfully do `<<"a">>` why is an error for `<<h>>` then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [<<>>/1-types](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1-types):

> When no type is specified, the default is integer:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> <<1, 2, 3>>
> <<1, 2, 3>>
> ```
>
> Elixir also accepts by default the segment to be a literal string or a
>   literal charlist, which are by default expanded to integers:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> <<0, "foo">>
> <<0, 102, 111, 111>>
> ```
>
> Variables or any other type need to be explicitly tagged:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> rest = "oo"
> iex> <<102, rest>>
> ** (ArgumentError) argument error
> ```
>
> We can solve this by explicitly tagging it as binary:
>
> ```elixir
> iex> rest = "oo"
> iex> <<102, rest::binary>>
> "foo"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it but you have to specify that it's a binary:

```
h = "a"
<<h::binary>>
"a"
```